# Read a public static variable value from class file inside a war which is in shared folder

Tags: java, class, classloader, war, urlclassloader

I need a code that loads the .class file which is in a war(Archive) file located in a shared location and then get the static variable value in it.

Following is the code which I have tried which results in ClassNotFoundException when invoking the Class.ForName method.

```
String warPath = "jar:file://" + sharedDrivePath +"/AppUIWebApp.war!";
URL inputURL = new URL(warPath);
conn = (JarURLConnection) inputURL.openConnection();
URLClassLoader jarLevelClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{conn.getURL()});
Class.forName("Java.File.Name",Boolean.FALSE,
      jarLevelClassLoader).getDeclaredField("staticVariable").get(null));
```

Can anyone guide me on how to fix this issue. The same code worked for jar file which is also in shared drive.

Comment: not sure but  are you confirm that `jar:file://` is correct way to read war? also as far as i know the war structure is diffrent it doest work like a jar, it need specila way to load in jvm which webserver is best in doing `ServletContext` is the best way to access loaded resources.

Comment: What's your overall goal, i.e. why do you need the value of that static variable? Loading stuff from classes in WARs not on your classpath sounds wrong.

Comment: @AmeyJadiye Right, `"jar:file://" + sharedDrivePath +"/AppUIWebApp.war!/WEB-INF/classes/` is more likely to work.  Note that sharedDrivePath should probably be URL-encoded or else it will probably fail if it contains "%", "+", or perhaps other characters.

Comment: @AmeyJadiye. I'm able to connect to the shared drive and access the files in the war file using the above code. As you said,there is a structural differences between war(web-inf/classes) and jar and even I thought that could be the reason for this issue.

Comment: @PhilippReichart I'm writing a utility that needs to compare the value of this static variable with the classes variable that is already loaded in my web-app. I won't be using the class loaded from war file for any other purpose expect reading the static variable.  Also,  I have created a new class loader and not initializing the class. Let me know if you foresee any issue

Comment: @bkail I have tried,"jar:file://" + sharedDrivePath +"/AppUIWebApp.war!/WEB-INF/classes/" approach as well. It didn't help in loading the class but can read the stream. Also I can read the xml files in the war file. May be I'm missing something.